# Is the integral $ \int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1} - 1} $ converges or diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Determine if the following integral diverges/converges, if it converges, is it absolutely or conditionally converges.

$$
\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1} - 1}
$$

### What i tried:

In that interval we know that: 
$$
0 < x
$$

Therefore we can write:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1} - 1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} - 1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2} - 1}
$$

$$
=  \frac{1}{x - 2} 
$$

Now lets try to calculate the integral, using limits, we get:

$$
\lim_{t \to 2^-}\int_{1}^{t}\frac{1}{x-2} = ln(x-2)|_{1}^{t} = ln(t-2) - ln(1-2)
$$

I cant calculate this integral, namely i dont get any limit that is a number.

I thought that maybe i will get to a form like this: 
$$
\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{(b-x)^\alpha}, \int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{(x-a)^\alpha}
$$

But also, if i will, and conclude that $ \int \frac{1}{x - 2}$ diverges in that interval, i couldnt use the comparison test to conclude about the original function.

Can i have a hint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to decide about convergence/divergence is the limit comparison test:

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-1}{x-1}= \left. \left(\sqrt{x^2-x+1}\right)'\right|_{x=1}$$ $$ =\left. \frac{2x-1}{2\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\right|_{x=1} = \frac 12$$

Since $\int_1^2\frac{dx}{x-1}$ is divergent, $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1} - 1}$ must be divergent, as well.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Note that we have

$$\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-1} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+1}{x(x-1)}\tag 1$$

How does the right-hand side of $(1)$ behave as $x\to 1^+$?  Does the improper integral $\int_1^2 \frac1{x-1}\,dx$ converge?

Comment: How did you know that? how did you think about it? to change that term in that way of $(1)$?

Comment: @Alon its called [rationalizing the denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_(mathematics)#Dealing_with_more_square_roots)

Answer (score 1):

It diverges.

Multiplying by the conjugate:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-1} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+1}{x(x-1)}$.

A partial fraction decomposition yields:

$\frac{1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}$ and therefore

$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+1}{x}-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+1}{x-1}$.

The right-hand side equals:

$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x} - \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x-1}$

Also, remark that $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x}dx < \infty$ and $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x} < \infty$, hence it suffices to show that $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}{x-1} dx$ diverges. Note that $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x-1} dx \geq \displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \frac{dx}{x-1}$.

Comment: Can you please explain me how did you know to change the term in that way as the change you start your post with?

Comment: @alon its called [rationalizing the denominator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_(mathematics)#Dealing_with_more_square_roots)

Answer (score 1):

First, do a change of coordinates: $y=x-1$. The integral then becomes

$$\int_1^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}-1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+y+1}-1}dy$$

Now, expand using the Taylor series around $0$ to get

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+y+1}-1}=\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{15 y}{8}-\frac{33 y^2}{16}+\cdots>\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3}{2}$$

This implies

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+y+1}-1}dy>\int_0^1\left(\frac{2}{y}-\frac{3}{2}\right)dy=-\frac{3}{2}+2\int_0^1\frac{1}{y}dy$$

However, this final integral diverges, implying that the original integral also diverges.